# Python - yfinance, add more rows with Dates

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I have a problem regarding a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` structure.
I have 2 columns which are `valid['Close']` and `valid['Predictions']`.
But there is still a column on the left named `Date`, which I cannot access. But the thing is, I want to add
now new rows with future dates. How to do that? The table looks like that:

```
                    Close    Predictions
Date
2018-12-20         10611.10   10802.74
...                 ...          ...
2021-09-24         15536.1    15503.6
```

And now I want to add something like this

```
                    Close    Predictions
Date
2018-12-20         10611.10   10802.74
...                 ...          ...
2021-09-24         15536.1    15503.6
2021-09-25         15434.1    15434.1
```

So I just want to append the structure with future dates.

Comment: This is a `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, let alone `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `Date` is technically not a column of the DataFrame, but its **index**. See the pandas [Intro to data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe). You can access the index with `valid.index`.

To add new rows, you could read or write the new rows into a new DataFrame just like the one you already have (same column and index names). Then you can use [`df.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to concatenate the two DataFrames.